# Time Expressions with "in"

Tags: meaning, prepositions

I have seen some examples about using "in" with time expressions. They give some examples as shown below:

> I will leave for vacation in a month. (Exactly one month from now I
>   will go on vacation.)
>
> We’ll be there in an hour.  (Exactly one hour will go by and then we
>   will arrive.)

But these comments confused me. Then I looked the usage of "in" up in a dictionary and it says about usage of "in" with time expressions :"***before or at the end of a particular period***". I think the comments and the definition in the dictionary contradict each other?

[dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/tr/s%C3%B6zl%C3%BCk/ingilizce/in)

I have examples of mine:

> 1- ***Dinner will be ready in ten minutes***. (Maybe dinner will be
>   ready at the 5th minute? or 8th. Does it strictly mean dinner will be
>   ready at the end of the ten minutes?)
>
> 2- ***My letter arrived in two days***. ( Does that mean it took
>   exactly two days to arrive? or Could it be just one day because he/she
>   doesnt remember the exact time?)
>
> 3- Imagine you are on the first day of a month and your friend says:
>   ***I will be going outside the country in this month***. (Does that mean he/she could go tomorrow or ten days later or at the end of the
>   month?)
>
> 4- ***He can run a mile in 5 minutes***. ( Does that mean he has to
>   spent entire 5 minutes to run a mile? Could it be 4 or 4.5 minutes?)

Comment: There's a potential difference between *We’ll be there **in** an hour* (best current estimate for arrival time is one hour from now), and *We’ll be there **within** an hour* (we don't expect to arrive *later* than an hour from now, but it might well be somewhat *earlier*).

Comment: @FumbleFingers But the dictionary give these definitions about in: "needing or using no more time than a particular amount of time" For example : "Can you finish the job in two weeks?" and the other definitions is that: "before or at the end of a particular period" For example : "I'm just setting off, so I should be with you in half an hour." https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like many other things in English, *before or at the end of a particular period* can be ambiguous. As with words that have multiple meanings, you can only tell what is actually meant in any given situation by its context.

For instance:

> I will be there ***in*** *an hour*.

This *normally* means to expect the person to arrive at the end of an hour—although they could still show up earlier than that.

However:

> I will be there *sometime* ***in*** *the next hour*.

Here, additional wording indicates that there is no set time—except for expecting the person to arrive *no later than* an hour from now. The use of *sometime* gives it the sense as *within*. But even if *sometime* isn't used, *the next* also conveys that as a subtle suggestion—more than just *an* does.

---

As the dictionary definition says, the word *in* can be used in both contexts.

Generally speaking, I'd say it's more common for *in* to mean *at the end of the time mentioned* than for it to mean *within the time period mentioned*. If you assume the first interpretation, you'll be right more often than not.

---

The conversational use of *in* is mostly understood, but it's still open to misinterpretation.

If somebody wants to deliberately convey an *explicit* piece of information about timing, then they would phrase it differently:

> I will be there *in* ***exactly*** *an hour.*
>   I will be there ***at*** *2:00 p.m.*

Comment: Most people I have seen describing the meaning of the "in" with time expressions ignore the before part(before or at the end of a particular period) of the description. They just say exactly 1 minutes, 5 days etc. from now.

Comment: I have one more question : As we know "in" with time expressions indicate before or at the end of a particular period so does "within". As far as I understand, I can use "in" and "within" interchangeably with time expressions if I want not to indicate  the  end of a period but sometime in the period?

Comment: @TalhaÖzden Using *within* doesn't necessarily exclude the end of a period—but it's more likely something will occur prior to that. However, as I said, *in* more commonly does indicate the end of a period. Barring other words to establish a context where that's not the case, simply replacing *in* with *within* would be the simplest way of expressing a time in a period.